# Clean object from nulls and undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written the following function which cleans nulls and undefined from an object, but for some reason it also removes key where the value is 0.

For example:

```
{
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 0
}
```

The function will remove key2, even though it should not.

**Here is the function:**

```
const cleanJson = function cleanJson (obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) !== '[object Object]') return obj;
    return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] && obj[key] !== 'delete').reduce((newObj, key) => {
        newObj[key] = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]) !== '[object Object]' ? obj[key] : cleanJson(obj[key]);
        return newObj;
    }, {});
};
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please read the description of the `json` tag, especially what is in capitals.

Comment: `0` is "falsy", so it gets removed. Your function also cleans up things that evaluate to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `Object.entries`:

```js
const myJSON = {key1:'value1', key2:0, key3:null, key4:undefined, key5:""};

const myCleanJSON = Object.entries(myJSON)
  .filter(([key, value]) => (value !== null && typeof value !== 'undefined'))
  .reduce((acc, b) => ((!acc.length) ? {...acc, [b[0]]: b[1] } : { [acc[0]] : acc[1], [b[0]]: b[1] }));
  
console.log(myCleanJSON);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is within

```
obj[key] && obj[key] !== 'delete'
```

When obj[key] == 0, would return false.

Answer (score 1):

Because `0` (as well as the empty `string` `""`) evaluates to false when cast to a Boolean, you need to explicitly check for `undefined` and `null`:

```js
let a = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 0,
  key3: null
}

function cleanProps(o) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(o) !== '[object Object]') return o
  for (key in o) {
    if([undefined, null].includes(o[key])) delete o[key]
  }
  return o
}

console.log(cleanProps(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that would solve your issue:

`obj[key] !== null && obj[key] !== undefined && obj[key] !== 'delete'`

Comment: You can just use `!=` to catch both `null` and `undefined`

Comment: And pick one or the other?

Comment: Yes, both `undefined != null` and `null != undefined` are `false`